# D3: Panning along date x axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, pan

I'm trying to display dates in the x axis and at the same time zoom it when you scroll.

So, I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var data =  [
    [{'x':20111001,'y':1},{'x':20111002,'y':6},{'x':20111003,'y':11},{'x':20111004,'y':1},{'x':20111005,'y':2},{'x':20111006,'y':12},{'x':20111007,'y':2},{'x':20111008,'y':3},{'x':20111009,'y':13},{'x':20111010,'y':3}],
    [{'x':20111001,'y':2},{'x':20111002,'y':2},{'x':20111003,'y':12},{'x':20111004,'y':2},{'x':20111005,'y':3},{'x':20111006,'y':1},{'x':20111007,'y':2},{'x':20111008,'y':7},{'x':20111009,'y':2},{'x':20111010,'y':7}],
    [{'x':20111001,'y':3},{'x':20111002,'y':10},{'x':20111003,'y':13},{'x':20111004,'y':3},{'x':20111005,'y':12},{'x':20111006,'y':14},{'x':20111007,'y':6},{'x':20111008,'y':1},{'x':20111009,'y':7},{'x':20111010,'y':9}],
    [{'x':20111001,'y':4},{'x':20111002,'y':4},{'x':20111003,'y':14},{'x':20111004,'y':14},{'x':20111005,'y':10},{'x':20111006,'y':15},{'x':20111007,'y':3},{'x':20111008,'y':0},{'x':20111009,'y':3},{'x':20111010,'y':12}]
    ];

    var colors = [
    'steelblue',
    'green',
    'red',
    'purple'
    ]

    var b =[];


    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

    data.forEach(function (d) {
        f = d;
        f.forEach(function(f){

            b.push(parseDate(String(f.x)));
        })
    })

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([d3.extent(b)])
    .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-1, 16])
    .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickSize(-height)
    .tickPadding(10)    
    .tickSubdivide(true)    
    .orient("bottom");  

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickPadding(10)
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickSubdivide(true)    
    .orient("left");

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);    



    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .call(zoom)
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "axis-label")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 10)
    .attr("x", -height/2)
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Ventas (Miles €)");

    svg.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

    var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")  
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });     

    svg.selectAll('.line')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .transition()
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .attr('stroke', function(d,i){          
        return colors[i%colors.length];
    })
    .attr("d", line);       

    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);


    var points = svg.selectAll('.dots')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "dots")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");   

    points.selectAll('.dot')
    .data(function(d, index){       
        var a = [];
        d.forEach(function(point,i){
            a.push({'index': index, 'point': point});
        });     
        return a;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('class','dot')
    .attr("r", 2.5)
    .attr('fill', function(d,i){    
        return colors[d.index%colors.length];
    })  
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + x(d.point.x) + "," + y(d.point.y) + ")"; }
        ).on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
            .duration(200)      
            .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(d.point.x + "K<br/>"  + d.point.y)  
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");    
        })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
            .duration(500)      
            .style("opacity", 0);   
        })

        function zoomed() {
            svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
            svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);   
            svg.selectAll('path.line').attr('d', line);  

            points.selectAll('circle').attr("transform", function(d) { 
                return "translate(" + x(d.point.x) + "," + y(d.point.y) + ")"; }
                );  
        }

    </script>
```

I can make it with numbers but can't implement it with dates. I've checked other examples and how they make it but can't find the way to code it in my chart.

I'd like to know how to display dates on x axis.

Comment: Something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367)?

Comment: Or maybe more like [this](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/area-gradient.html)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thank you very much, but it's way too complex for what I really need...

Comment: @AmeliaBR That's right. Where I can find the code? Or just a similar example?

Comment: If you right click on the page it should give you an option to view the source.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question how to make the axis dates instead of just numbers? Or is it how to make the axis pannable? If it's the first, use code like this:

```
var x=d3.time.scale()
    .domain([minDate,maxDate])
```

The minDate and maxDate have to be [javascript Date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: he meant, he wanted to PAN the date axis. right now he is trying to do this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3892919 example by @mbostock

Comment: Something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756464/d3-panning-chart-with-dates