# D3 Panning Chart with Dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to get a multi-line date based chart to pan nicely across the X date axis and I simply cannot figure out what the problem is.

I have the zoom behaviour set up in the code but it's just not performing as expected.  If you click on a point in a line and scroll it appears to be scrolling the axis, if it click on the labels in the axis it also scrolls but the actual visualisation of data doesn't scroll.

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .scaleExtent([1, 1])
    .on("zoom", function () {
        svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".lines").call(xAxis);
    });

svg.call(zoom);
```

Also if you click directly on the back ground the mouse event doesn't seem to make it's way to the control at all.

I read a few examples on this and each seem to take a vastly different approach which I've tried but none have worked for my chart.

There are possibly a number of issues that exist as barriers to getting this working so I thought the best way to illustrate the problem was in a JsFiddle.

[D3 Chart Panning Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jammer/wvL422zq/)

What I'm trying to achieve is when there is a lot of data to visualise the chart can adapt to the data set and allow the data to extend beyond the bounds of the chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently clicking on the background does not allow panning because you have applied zoom behavior to the g element not to the svg.

```
var svg = d3.select('#host')
        .data(plotData)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("id", "history-chart")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .call(zoom);
```

Right now on zoom you have updated x and y axes but not the visualization. So you have update the lines and circles also like this.

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .x(x)
        .scaleExtent([1, 1])
        .on("zoom", function () {
            svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
            svg.select(".lines").call(xAxis);
            svg.selectAll("path.lines")
               .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });
            svg.selectAll("circle")           
               .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })                              
               .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value); }); 
        });
```

Since you are panning the map you will have to use clip path for restricting visualization from moving outside the chart

```
var clip = svg.append("svg:clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("svg:rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
```

Apply clip path to the g elment which contains lines and cicrles.

```
 var attribute = svg.selectAll(".attribute")
        .data(plotData)
        .enter().append("svg:g")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .attr("class", "attribute");
```

Comment: Going on from this how do I set the initial "zoom level" of the xAxis?  I want he points "spread out" more initially.